# ENOSPC Error in create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

[create-react-app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Fsg.png)

I get this error message when I run `yarn start` from my terminal... I've tried `sudo killall node` and many other process to clear the `i-node` yet no success.

I have also downgraded my `create-react-app` version to version 1.5.1 and yet I still have these errors...

Please can anyone help out?

Answer (score 25):

You're most likely hitting the Unix limit of how many files a process can watch.

The following command should help:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: This is what I got when I ran the command.

     `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288`

Comment: This is expected. Restarting `yarn start` should work.

Answer (score 2):

By default linux machine puts some limit on number of programs inotify program can watch/monitor.

On running the react development server, the create-react-app ask the inotify program to monitor more files than its limit. Babel and webpack in the creat-react-app are using chokidar to monitor files which in turn is using inotify program to monitor them, hence this crosses the limit of inotify program.

By running the following command the limit of inotify program is increased and issue is solved.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue twice...
first time i tried deleting whole node modules using

`rm -rf ./node_modules`

and installed it again (npm install) and it worked.

BUT, second time it did not.

this time i tried cleaning the unused dependencies from npm modules using,
`npm clean-install`

and it started the server again.

as it removes the unused dependencies thus decreasing the number of files to watch in a single process.